# There are no more than $p$ elements divisible by $p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $p$ is prime number has the form $3k+2$. Prove that in the set $$S=\{ y^6-x^3-2\mid x,y\in \mathbb{Z}:0\le x\le p-1, 0\le y\le p-1 \}$$ there are no more than $p$ elements divisible by $p$.

I really have no idea to solve it. Help me.

Comment: Pigeonhole or perhaps root counting. Seems very difficult, in any case.

Comment: @DVdivi, what's the source of this problem?

Comment: @HVxvejjw: In my last exam

Comment: Here is my  problem but it's vietnamese https://scontent.fhan3-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/72033597_467839673942006_5600846939798110208_n.png?_nc_cat=101&_nc_oc=AQkX26vlaeBnzBWgDXkpJtoaEz4D1Byj9BLCvbbrUImEQbklhkTNigxYrBGekwfj4qE&_nc_ht=scontent.fhan3-3.fna&oh=12f1e2dddfceb419c5024ae1ed203aa4&oe=5E1D2927

Comment: @DVdivi, Did you do the first part of this question?

Comment: @HVxvejjw: yes, i used Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Since $p-1$ is not divisible by $3$, the field $\mathbb F_p$ does not contain any non-trivial roots of unity. As a result, the mapping $z\mapsto z^3$ is a bijection of $\mathbb F_p$; that is, any element of $\mathbb F_p$ can be uniquely represented as a cube. Consequently, any element of $\mathbb F_p$ has a unique cube root.

To show that your set $S$ contains at most $p$ elements divisible by $p$, just notice that there are at most $p$ pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb F_p\times\mathbb F_p$ with $y^6-x^3-2=0$: namely, for every given $y\in\mathbb F_p$, we are forced to take $x$ to be the cube root of $y^6-2$.

Comment: The set $S$ is actually counting numbers of the form $y^6-x^3-2$, not pairs $(x,y)$.  So unless you show the map $(x,y)\mapsto y^6-x^3-2$ is injective, you can only conclude $S$ has at most $p$ elements.

Comment: And in fact, for $p=2$, $S$ has only $1$ element, since the two solutions are $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ which give the same element of $S$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: thank you for the comment; I have edited the solution.